# Position an element relative to another in one dimension only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make something like margin notes that can be inserted in a paragraph but will always be moved to the right of a parent, and take up no space in their original position. Basically like `float: right;` but I want it to be *outside* the parent element, not inside it.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#column {
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.note {
  display: inline-block; /* Make it so that width works. */
  width: 0; /* So that it doesn't take up any space in its original position. */
  position: relative; /* So we can move it from its original position. */
  left: calc(100% + 10px); /* Move it. */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="column">
    <p><span class="note">foo.bar</span>This is a paragraph that
    starts with a note. I want the note to be to the right.
    As you can see this works.</p>

    <p>But unfortunately it doesn't <span class="note">foo.bar</span> work
    if the note is in the middle of a paragraph.</p>

    <p><span class="note">foo bar</span>And it always wraps because
    I had to set the width to 0.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this without Javascript, and without changing where the `note` element is within the HTML?

Comment: Use `position: absolute` for **.note** and remove `width` property. Add `position: relative` in `#column`

Comment: It's not quite perfect because I really want to position relative to `column` even if there are `position: relative` things between them, but that seems to be impossible so I'll go with your solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#column {
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
#column p{
    position: relative;
}
.note {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 0; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: calc(100% + 10px); 
}
```